# Select multiple options when option in another multi select is selected

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I am importing a CSV file, and adding it to my database table. On the next page I want to add information to the data that was just inserted into the table. This data will be inserted into the `import_map` table.

When a Table1Model option is selected it will select the options in the Table2Model select box, according to the `map_table`, using Ajax. I can't just create an `id` field in the `map_table` and insert that into the `import_map` table because the user can select options in the Table2Model select box that are not related to `table1`.

My thought is to just build an array with selected values in the `add()` method. But the problem is that it doesn't seem to be hitting the `if($this->request->is('ajax'))` section of the `add()` method. At least, it's not doing anything at all when an option is selected.

map_table

```
+-------------+-------------+
| `table1_id` | `table2_id` |
+-------------+-------------+
| 1           | 1           |
+-------------+-------------+
| 1           | 2           |
+-------------+-------------+
| 2           | 1           |
+-------------+-------------+
```

table1

```
+------------------+
| `id` | `name`    |
+------+-----------+
| 1    | Table_1_1 |
+------+-----------+
| 2    | Table_1_2 |
+------+-----------+
```

table2

```
+------------------+--------------+
| `id` | `name`    | `url`        |
+------+-----------+--------------+
| 1    | Table_2_1 | example.com  |
+------+-----------+--------------+
| 2    | Table_2_2 | example2.com |
+------+-----------+--------------+
```

import

```
+------------------+---------+--------+------------+
| `id` | `country` | `month` | `year` | `imported` |
+------+-----------+---------+--------+------------+
| 1    | USA       | 05      | 2016   | 0          |
+------+-----------+---------+--------+------------+
| 2    | CAN       | 08      | 2015   | 0          |
+------+-----------+---------+--------+------------+
```

import_map

```
+-------------+---------+
| `id`        | int(11) |
| `table1_id` | int(5)  |
| `table2_id` | int(5)  |
| `import_id` | int(7)  |
+-------------+---------+
```

Import Controller

```
<?php

App::uses('AdminController', 'Controller');

/**
 * Class ImportController
 */
class ImportController extends AdminController
{
    public $components = array('RequestHandler');

    public function add()
    {
        $importedIds = $this->Session->read('importedIds');
        if(!isset($importedIds))
        {
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }

        if($this->request->is('post'))
        {
            # Save logic here
        }

        $this->loadModel('Table1Model');
        $table1 = $this->Table1Model->find('list', array(
            'fields' => array(
                'id',
                'name'
            ),
            'order' => 'name ASC'
        ));
        $this->set('table1', $table1);

        $this->loadModel('Table2Model');
        $table2 = $this->Table2Model->find('list', array(
            'fields' => array(
                'id',
                'name'
            ),
            'order' => 'name ASC'
        ));

        $selectedTable2Ids = array();
        if($this->request->is('ajax'))
        {
            # Build what options to select.
            foreach($this->request['data']['Table1Model']['table1_ids'] as $table1)
            {
                $selectedTable2Ids = '';
            }
        }

        $this->set('table2', $table2);
        $this->set('selectedTable2Ids', $selectedTable2Ids);

        $this->render('add');
    }
}
```

Import Model

```
<?php

App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

/**
 * Class Import
 */
class Import extends AppModel
{
    public    $useTable    = 'import';
    public    $hasMany     = array(
        'ImportMap' => array(
            'class' => 'ImportMap',
            'foreign_key' => 'import_id'
        )
    );
}
```

ImportMap Model

```
<?php

App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

/**
 * Class ImportMap
 */
class ImportMap extends AppModel
{
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Import' => array(
            'class' => 'Import',
            'foreign_key' => 'id'
        ),
        'Table1',
        'Table1'
    );
}
```

Table1Model

```
<?php

App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

/**
 * Class Table1
 */
class Table1 extends AppModel
{
    public $useTable = 'table1';
    public $hasMany  = array(
        'MapTable',
        'ImportMap'
    );
}
```

Table2Model

```
<?php

App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

/**
 * Class Table2
 */
class Table2 extends AppModel
{
    public $useTable = 'table2';
    public $hasMany  = array(
        'MapTable',
        'ImportMap'
    );
```

add.ctp

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('MapTableModel'); ?>
    <div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <?php
                echo $this->Form->input('Table1Model.table1_id', array(
                    'id' => 'table1',
                    'required' => false,
                    'multiple' => 'multiple',
                    'type' => 'select',
                    'class' => 'form-control',
                    'label' => false,
                    'options' => $table1
                ));
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('Table2Model.table2_id', array(
                'class' => 'form-control',
                'required' => false,
                'type' => 'select',
                'multiple' => 'multiple',
                'id' => 'table2',
                'label' => false,
                'options' => $table2,
                'default' => $selectedTable2Ids
            ));
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php echo $this->Form->end('Add'); ?>

# Loading jQuery here
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#table1").on('click', function() {
        var ids = $(this).val();
        if (ids) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo Router::url(array("controller" => "import", "action" => "add"), true); ?>',
                data: {table1_ids: ids},
                cache: false,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#table2').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I call that chained dropdowns and you can find an example [here](http://sandbox.dereuromark.de/sandbox/ajax-examples/chained-dropdowns). The source code is also available.